# How do I resolve No constructor with 0 arguments on @SpringBootApplication

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm running a Spring Boot App (4.3.5) in eclipse(STS 3.8.3) and getting the following error:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean' ProcessCardEvents.java  /field-card/src/main/java/ws/daley/field/fieldcard  Unknown Spring Beans Problem

Here's my program:

```
package ws.daley.field.fieldcard;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ProcessCardEvents
{
}
```

Actually there was a bunch more, but I stripped it down. There is an error marker on the java file in Package Explorer and error marker on the tab in the source pane, but no line is marked with an error.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you have a non zero argument constructor in your entity `class`. In this case, Java compiler won't provide a default constructor (documentataion [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)) and Sprint Data needs `default` constructor to instantiate a bean using `reflection`, so all you need to do is to add a `default` constructor, e.g.:

```
public ProcessCardEvents(){}
```

Comment: That's not it. I put default in all 4 classes and it didn't solve the problem. I've rebuilt the project from another one so I don't need to fix this. However, I certainly don't know why it occurred.